# Filling a dictionary whose values are a list container

Tags: arcpy, python, dictionary

```py
import arcpy, datetime
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Number of days to subtract
tdelta = datetime.timedelta(days=21)    

fiberCable = r'C:\Users\broadhurstn\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\FIBERCABLE'
conduit = r'C:\Users\broadhurstn\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\CONDUIT'
fibercableToConduit = r'C:\Users\broadhurstn\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\FibercableToConduit'
unc = r'\\Bvweb104draco\e\08_Scripts\referenceScripts\Conduit Export\ConduitExports.gdb\TampaConduit'

# Populate a dictionary that maps segment ID to the placed/planned date
segment_dates = defaultdict(list)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fiberCable, ['segmentid', 'bv_cable_placed_planned']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        segment_dates[row[0]].append(row[1])

# Populate a dictionary that maps conduit ID to a two-item list containing segment ID and placed/planned date
ftcs = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fibercableToConduit, ['conduitipid', 'segmentid']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Use .get() so that it won't fail if a segment ID isn't in the dictionary
        ftcs[row[0]] = [row[1], segment_dates.get(row[1])]

# Populate conduit 'bv_placed_est' field and subtract 21 days       
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(unc, ['ipid', 'bv_placed_est']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        ipid = row[0]
        for k,v in ftcs.items():
            if ipid == str(k):
                # tdelta will not work on null values
                if v[1] is not None:
                    row[1] = min(v[1]) - tdelta
                    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

The above code and below feature class table produce a dictionary that fills as follows:

`{u'248bdd3a-a13c-44b4-b592-b64a843fb0bc': [u'{2AC71409-C59E-49E1-A35B-61CD19885A2A}', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 0, 0)]}`

**How do I add a multiple values to the dictionary keys using the below feature class table and have it choose the earliest date of the bunch?**

[image]

Notice how the value in the dictionary matches "segment ID" in this feature class. I want to have the the SearchCursor look at the current dictionary, see if there is a value that matches the "SegmentID" field values and append the **EARLIEST** "Cable Placed Planned" to it's corresponding dictionary item as a second value. **There could be multiple 'Cable Placed Planned' dates in the form of a value associated with a key.**

**Expected output for the first item:**

`{u'248bdd3a-a13c-44b4-b592-b64a843fb0bc': [u'{2AC71409-C59E-49E1-A35B-61CD19885A2A}', datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 28, 0, 0)}, etc...`

**The key could have 1 value, or 20 values associated with it and I need to sift through those values for the earliest date and append it to the conduit feature class field.**

**Working code above only takes a single value per key, but can't deal with instances when there are numerous values that need to be associated with a key.**

Comment: Looking at your expected output and screen shot why have you chosen 12/14/2017 and not 1/14/2017? How are you defining earliest? Earliest in each year?

Comment: Have you tried using `in` to see if the key is already there, and then appending to the list, otherwise initialize it with a value that is a list with just one element. https://www.mkyong.com/python/python-check-if-key-exists-in-dictionary/

Comment: @Hornbydd Earliest date period, so 1/14/2017 before 12/14/2017. this particular key/value should choose 1/14/2016 as the date to append to the key, as it's the earliest.

Comment: You should use defaultdict(list) like i showed you in your previous question. You cant change a normal dictionary while iterating over it. Are you saying you already have the dictionary with `datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 0, 0)` and then want to add values from another feature class? What happened to the datetime value first added, cant see it in your example

Comment: @BERA I'm saying when the first dictionary 'segment_dates' gets populated with the date value, I need it to have logic in place to take the earliest date associated with that 'Segment ID'. There could be a single 'Segment ID' associated to one date, or numerous like in the case above of 'Segment ID' 2AC71409-C59E-49E1-A35B-61CD19885A2A. For the case above we'd want the 'segment_dates' dictionary to look like this '{u'{2AC71409-C59E-49E1-A35B-61CD19885A2A}': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 14, 0, 0)}' where it's taking the earliest date of the bunch.

Answer (score 2):

This line is essentially overwriting the entry in the `ftcs` dictionary within the loop:

```
ftcs[row[0]] = [row[1], segment_dates.get(row[1])]
```

Hence you ending up with just one date entry.

I think you need to explore the dictionary method `has_key()` to check for the existing entry then return the value (your list) with `ftcs[row[0]]` ,lets call it `mylist`, update `mylist` with the required date and then use the line such as below to overwrite the entry, now with your updated list.

```
ftcs[row[0]] = mylist
```

Comment: Used suggestions from Hornbydd and @BERA to arrive at the correct solution. The code has been updated in my initial post to the correct answer.